# I have to choose between IBM X3650 M4 and HP DL380pG8. What to consider?

Tags: dedicated-server

I have to choose between IBM X3650 M4 and HP DL380pG8 servers. Both are 6-cores Xeon e5-2620 with 64 Mb of RAM and the same price. What factors should I consider to make a choice between them? They seems to be the same in performance. What to take?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ease of management, cost, user mindshare and supportability.

Nobody really focuses on IBM server hardware these days, as they've exited the Intel server market. However, there's [lots of HP information](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/hp-proliant) and knowledge out there.

On paper, the servers will perform the same because they use the same chipset and have similar specs.